# Surpress opening of text editor when using aws lambda update-function-code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When running

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://my-zip-file.zip"
```

it opens an editor with the details upon completion. How can I prevent this, or how can I add a command to automatically close it? Can I pipe `:q` into my command or something similar?

Comment: What editor? Where do you  execute the command (windows, linux, bash terminal)?

Comment: For me nano, when using mac terminal

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: I want it out of my face

Answer (score 4):

Feature you are looking for is called AWS CLI pager and there is several ways how to suppres it

### Disable for single command

Use `--no-cli-pager` option

```sh
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://my-zip-file.zip --no-cli-pager
```

### Disable permanently

##### Using environment variable

First option to disable aws cli pager permanently is to set `AWS_PAGER` to nothing in shell initialization file (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, ...)

```sh
export AWS_PAGER=""
```

##### Using AWS CLI config

Second option is to use CLI configuration. Then you can have different settings for different `AWS_PROFILE`

```sh
aws configure set cli_pager ""
```

###### Config example

```
[default]
...
cli_pager =

[admin]
...
cli_pager = less
```